# can't connect to mysql in playframework

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

I'm trying to connect to MySQL in Playframework 2.4 (I created project play java).

I've installed mysql 5.7 in mac by brew and I created user and database.

And I added some configurations to application.conf and build.sbt in play.

Here's application.conf

```
    db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testplay"
    db.default.user="test"
    db.default.password= "test"
```

Here's buid.sbt.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
 "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.35"
)
```

I've done 'sbt' and 'activator run' in the project folder.

However when I connected to http://localhost:9000/ , it returned "configuration error cannot connect to database[db]".

the application log summury is

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [db]]


Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:70)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    ... 66 common frames omitted


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:784)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConfig.toHikariConfig(HikariCPModule.scala:141)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:57)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54
```

Would you tell me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't mean to patronize but MySQL is running right? What version of Play, and I assume you are using Play-Java?

Comment: Thanks for you commets!  Play version is 2.4 and yes ,I 'm using Play-Java.I thought MySQL is running .. (I checked it by ps aux | grep mysqld ) But, there may be some problem in MySQL.

Comment: your config and dependencies look Ok so I would first rule out that MySQL is ok, and your `testplay` schema and credentials are correct.

Comment: I see.Username and password are correct ,and privileges on testplay is also  ok.And,I tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost  but i didn't work..

Comment: I think SQL+ command line client ships with MySql - you could try connecting to your schema via that client to check its not your Play app.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I couldn't come up with idea of connecting to mysql via client.  I can't find SQL+. but , I have another mysql client and can connect to schema via that.So, I begin to think mysql is running right....

Comment: I solved the problem!   i added dbconf in 'db{  }' in application.conf. I added it to 'play.db{}' and it worked.I could confirm mysql is running right ,so I cheked the conffile.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace, it seems like the configuration parameter is no longer just `url` but `jdbcUrl. Try this:

```
...
db.default.jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testplay"
// you may also need to change user to username
db.default.username=test
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!!    I tried your advice but i retured the same error and logs...

Comment: This not  a solution at all.

Answer (score 2):

The correct key to specify the user name  in Play 2.4 and newer is `username`, not `user`. You can get more info in the [JDBC Settings - Reference](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsJDBC#Reference) section.

```
db.default.username="test"
```

With 2.3 and probably older versions, the key you used (`user`) was the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason for connection error is username parameter you pointed out , and i added url to wrong place in application.conf..(I added it to 'db {    }'. I wrote it out of db{} and it worked)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the proper connection url to mySql should contain user name and password, in spite they are defined separately - at least this is what I am doing.
In your case this is something like this:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user="test"
db.default.password= "test"   
db.default.url="mysql://test:test@localhost/testplay"
```

I prefer to use parametric url:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user="test"
db.default.password= "test"   
db.host="localhost"
db.schema="testplay"
db.default.url="mysql://"${db.default.username}":"${db.default.password}"@"${dbhost}"/"${dbschema}
```

This probably looks to your more sophisticated, that the first url, but this prevents bugs and provides better flexibility. In this way you can easily substitute the property value without breaking by mistake the url format.

You should probably also take care to set the **db.default.jndiName** property - I don't know, id it is relevant for jdbc. I am using JPA/hibernate and it is needed - I use the value defined in persistence.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I couldn't come up with the idea of using paramatic url.